# Babel register tutorial is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-register

I was simply following a tutorial 'https://kleopetrov.me/2016/03/18/everything-about-babel/',

There are two files:

```
$ cat index.js
console.log('Hello Babel');

$ cat register.js
require('babel-register');
require('index.js');
```

When I run node register.js

Instead of printing out Hello World, it says:"

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'index.js'
```

Where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path to require your local files,

```
require('./index.js');
```